# "By an abuse of terminology" in German

Tags: terminology, translation-request, mathematical-german

How to translate the standard mathematical mantra "By an abuse of terminology, …" into German?

E.g.

> An *environment* is a family of partial maps $\eta_M\colon X_M\dashrightarrow\dots$ for $M\in S$ such that …
>
> By an abuse of terminology, if the sets $X_M$ for $M\in S$ are pairwise disjoint, an *environment* is a partial map $\eta\colon\bigcup_{M\in S}X_M\dashrightarrow\dots$ such that …

I'm sure German has a standard phrase for that, but it simply won't occur to me now!

Comment: Google Translate does "Durch einen Missbrauch der Notation..." It's probably not idiomatic German, but it might get you by.

Comment: In Germany, terminology abuses you.

Comment: I'm not sure that German has a standard phrase. My professors used to say "par abus de notation" if it was specifically about notation, "par abus de langage" otherwise. Sounds like a loaned phrase.

Comment: @DanielFischer Specifically, it sounds loaned from French.

Comment: C'est vrai, @G.Sassatelli.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://books.google.at/books?id=rCEpBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=missbrauch+von+notation+in+mathematik&source=bl&ots=wLLaAuepke&sig=Y1D4vJM04AS45prR--5enNjuWvw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqq5_AhrXaAhVLYlAKHUNbD7EQ6AEIXDAE#v=onepage&q=missbrauch%20von%20notation%20in%20mathematik&f=false) is a citation: "Man beachte, dass die Benutzung des Gleichheitszeichens in der Landau-Notation *in gewisser Weise einen Missbrauch* darstellt".

Comment: Fair enough, Anush Taraz is a reference good enough to me.